# Drop down menu text not centering

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to center the text in each header of the drop-down menu while having the text in the actual "drop-down" portion of the menu aligned to the left.

I've got the drop-down portion aligned how I wanted, but I can't seem to get the headers to align.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Clothing Selector</title></head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="main.css" />

  <body background="Pictures/background.png">    
      <h2 id="home_subhead">Keep Track Of Your Clothes :-)</h2>

<video id="band_shirts_banner" width="20%" autoplay loop>
  <source src="band_shirts_banner.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>


<div id="menu">
      <ul class="menu" align="center">
        <li><a>Shirts</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="band_shirts.html">Band Shirts</a></li>
            <li><a href="night_shirts.html">Sleeping Shirts</a></li>
            <li><a href="trash_shirts.html">Trash Shirts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a>Pants</a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href="royal_bones.html">Royal Bones</a></li>
            <li><a href="rude.html">Rude</a></li>   
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a>Shoes</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="converse.html">Converse</a></li>
            <li><a href="boots.html">Boots</a></li>   
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
ul, ul ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu > li > a {
    background-color: #616975;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(114, 122, 134)),to(rgb(80, 88, 100)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0));<!---------COLOR OF BAR @ BOTTOM OF DROPDOWN LIST---------->
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#727a86', EndColorStr='#505864');
    border-bottom: 0.0625em solid #33373d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #878e98;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #878e98;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #878e98;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.75em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    text-indent: 2.75em;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.menu ul li a {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 0.0625em solid #efeff0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.75em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    text-indent: 2.75em;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.923em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: black;<!---------DROPDOWN MENU TEXT COLOR---------->

}
.menu ul li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: 0.0625em solid #33373d;<!---------COLOR OF BAR @ BOTTOM OF DROPDOWN LIST---------->

}
.menu > li > a:hover, .menu > li > a.active {
    background-color: #35afe3;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(69, 199, 235)),to(rgb(38, 152, 219)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0));<!---------COLOR OF HEADER WHEN HOVERING---------->
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#45c7eb', EndColorStr='#2698db');
    border-bottom: 0.0625em solid #103c56;<!---------COLOR OF THIN BAR @ BOTTOM OF HEADER---------->
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #6ad2ef;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #6ad2ef;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #6ad2ef;
}

.menu > li > ul li a:before{
    content: '▶ ';
    font-size: .5em;
    color: black;<!---------COLOR OF ARROWS ON THE SIDE OF DROPDOWN LIST---------->
}

.menu > li > ul li:hover a,
.menu > li > ul li:hover a span,
.menu > li > ul li:hover a:before {
    color: #32373D;<!---------COLOR OF TEXT IN DROPDOWN LIST---------->
}

.menu li {
    float:left;
    width:15em;
}

ul li ul{
    display: none;
    }

    ul li:hover ul{
    display: block; /* display the dropdown */
    }
```

[image: See how "Pants" isn't quite in the middle?]

See how "Pants" isn't quite in the middle?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j8C23/2/, is that what you are after? It's the code of the deleted post with `text-indent` set to 0 in `.menu > li > a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `text-align: center;` on the part that you want to center in your CSS or HTML code.

Or you may use `<center>` tag to each header that you want to center.

What I did is I removed the `text-indent: 2.75em;` on your `.menu > li > a` design in CSS.

I think that's the reason why your header text wasn't centered.

Comment: I've tried that, but something odd happens...
The text becomes centered, but it becomes displayed hovering over the menu instead of inside of it, as well as knocking the other labels out of there place.

Comment: remove this `text-indent: 2.75em;` on your CSS code

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was after!
I'm 16 and VERY new to programming. That being so, I don't exactly understand what all this means. Working on it, but for now, I guess I'll be referencing this site lol